# after apt-get full-upgrade error on calling firefox

Tags: 18.04, firefox, lts

I receive error messages like this one:

```
(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:32569): dconf-WARNING **: 14:32:38.771: Unable to open /var/lib/snapd/desktop/dconf/profile/user: Keine Bere
chtigung
[Parent 32515, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (69): Die Verbindung wurde vom Kommunikationspartner zurückgesetzt: file /build/fir
efox-y_KX3Y/firefox-69.0.1+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 358
```

This is after running the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get full-upgrade
```

Comment: `snap list` please edit your question for output.